# How to Show Global Menubar in Fullscreen?

Tags: unity, fullscreen

In some applications (atom.io, terminal, gedit, Firefox), pressing <kbd>f11</kbd> will enter fullscreen mode. In fullscreen mode, I would like to aces the global menus(file, edit, view, etc.). I would expect the menubar to drop down when I move the mouse up to the top of the screen, but that doesn't happen. Is there any way to get this behavior? If not, is there any way to access items in the menubar without exiting fullscreen?

Comment: In Unity, there is the so-called "HUD". It opens if you briefly press the `Alt` key. You can enter a search term there and it will show you corresponding options from the current window's menus. It doesn't let you browse the menus in their hierarchical structure though, so you'd have to know already what you're looking for.

Comment: @ByteCommander the HUD does not show all the menubar options. for example, there is no 'new window' command available. however, after checking the unity keyboard shortcuts by holding super (oops. i should have done this before asking the question), I saw that alt-f10 opens the menubar. I tried it, and it opens the menus alright, but they are all blank, and I cannot figure out how to show the options. Any ideas?

Comment: I can reproduce the blank menus. Might be worth writing a bug report on Launchpad.